# How does a Kafka consumer choose from which topic to poll next?

Tags: java, .net, apache-kafka, messaging

Suppose, I have a consumer subscribed to multiple topics.
Which topic is chosen, when I do a poll?
I'm using RdKafka .Net for the client. Is there a way I can influence, which topic is chosen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consumer does poll for all topic partitions (that are not paused). The broker decides what data to return. You cannot influence the broker's behavior directly.

Not sure if `RdKafka` has an API to pause and resume partitions. I only now Java `KafkaConsumer`, that offers methods `#pause()` and `#resume()`.